# Edit the row height for tableview Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In the tableView I am having a web view, and the height cell should be equal to the webView, i have tried to edit the row height of the cell by the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as ActivitiesCell

    return cell.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
}
```

But i got this exception  when initializing the var cell : "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x306d2c): 
so how can i make the height of the cell dynamic depending on the webview height ? 
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is that you are trying to access the cell inside tableView's `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. The cell is not created till yet and does not exist.

The tableview calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method followed by `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to create the cell.

First `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called to get the height of the cell at index path. After this `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called in which cell is created for the corresponding index path.

As cell is created in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called before this so you cannot access a cell there(as it is not created yet, otherwise `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` as above). And in order to return the dynamic height of the cell for the corresponding index path you should calculate the the height on the basis of data modal rather than trying to access the cell.

Comment: you meant to create a webView variable, and try to calculate it's height, then return this height for the heightForRowAtIndexPath ??

Comment: if you are able to calculate the height of the cell with data only in heightForRowAtIndexPath: then you should calculate the height there else insert a check if (dynamic height calculated)return cellsDynamicHeight else return default height.

After returning default height create cell inside cellForRowAtIndexPath: and create the web view there let the content being loaded when the content is loaded successfully than calculate the height based on the content, update modal and reload the corresponding row.

Comment: Reloading the corresponding row will return dynamically calculated height this time from heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: do you have an example about dynamic height for cell ?

Comment: for detailed tutorial, you can refer

http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: for basic info, you can refer
 http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/1/30/dynamic-table-view-cells-in-swift-xcode-6-ios-8-tutorial